# How do I setup a PHP website on Oracle WebLogic

Tags: php, oracle, apache, weblogic

I have a server running oracle linux and has Oracle WebLogic. How can I set it up so that if you go to my website on port 80 it runs of files on WebLogic. I only have command line access, and the reason im using web logic is because apache wont work on oracle linux.
I dont plan on changing OS.

Connah

Answer (score 1):

See if this could help you: http://quercus.caucho.com

Quercus is Caucho Technology's fast, open-source, 100% Java implementation of the PHP language. Quercus is a feature of Caucho Technology's Resin Application Server and is built into Resin - there is no additional download/install. Developers using Resin can launch PHP projects without having to install the standard PHP interpreter (http://www.php.net) as Quercus takes on the role of the PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not waiting for an answer but for all folks who came here to find Java - PHP integration here is an article on oracle.com -
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/oracle-java-zend-server-152557.html

Now I would mention 2 obvious things:

1. You need to know both Java and PHP.
2. If you are using Oracle 11/12 G with PHP this is the best way to do so because the [other way](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php) doesn't work and is not even maintained.